# What is $scope in jquery referring to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've see the below get used but can't find any documentation on `$scope`. What exactly is it capturing?

`$scope.find('selector')...`

Comment: Could you add more code to show where it is being used?

Comment: `$scope` is not specific to jQuery. How is it defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) construct. The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller). The scope is an object with the available properties and methods. The scope is available for both the view and the controller.

You have more detailed explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp).

Comment: The controller of what? The OP doesn't necessarily realize this is an angular construct.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Angular construct, not jQuery. `$scope` refers to the state of the entire Angular project; It's where all the data is stored that is bound to the templates. A change to `$scope` will be instantly reflected in the DOM.

Do note that Angular (at least version 1.x) relied on jQuery and has facilities in it to do jQuery-like functionality; One part was even called jQuery-lite. However, Angular uses jQuery, jQuery does not use Angular and `$scope` is not a jQuery concept.

**Update:** It has been mentioned in the comments that this could possibly just be a variable named `$scope`. This is totally possible since Javascript variables are allowed to start with a `$`. Often, people will prefix variables this way to indicate that the variables contain a jQuery object/element. However, this seems awfully coincidental.

Comment: It can just be a variable

Answer (score -1):

$scope is basically part of angularjs. It shows the scope of you controller in which you are working. $scope.find('selector') will find nothing this is not the correct syntax to capture any DOM element in angularjs.

Comment: Please update your answer and format your code blocks properly using the editor tools.